# Get code from Outlook Calendar API using Oauth2

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, outlook-calendar

I'm working with calendar API using .net core and Angular.
I finished all the steps using Google Calendar API.
Now I want to do it using Outlook Calendar API.
So first of all I need a function in Angular so i can connect to my account ang get a code(Oauth2)
which i will use it in backend to get my token(because i want to register them in my databe).
Well this is my function with Google API

```
  handleAuthClick() {
    let self = this;
    gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().grantOfflineAccess()
      .then(value => {
        const optionsParams = {
          params: new HttpParams()
            .set('code', value.code)
        };
        self.http.get("http://localhost:59933/api/UserCode", optionsParams)
          .subscribe(data => {
            console.log(data);
          })
      });
  }
```

I think i need this [link](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fuser.read&state=12345) in the function maybe or a library?
  Can anyone help with the function of Outlook Calendar API
  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It's recommended to  use [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/) for accessing Microsoft 365 services including Outlook .

For Angular , you can refer to tutorial : [Get started with Microsoft Graph and Angular](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started/angular) . It provides SDK and code samples in Angular .

There are also several Angular examples available on GitHub: https://github.com/search?q=angular+sample+user:microsoftgraph&type=Repositories

In addition , your link is showing that use Authorization Code Flow to get access token for Microsoft Graph API(scope is `https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read`) , you can use Implicit Flow in a javascript based application .